# Aggregate sub-query not producing expected results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables and there's a one to many relationship between the two. My query has a `group by` and I want to determine if there are any results in the 2nd table that match some criteria. I couldn't figure it out with a sub-query and tried the following code, but it's not giving you the results you expect.

```
CASE WHEN 
        (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN a.ContentId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END as 'HasAttachments'
```

Basically, I am trying to figure out if my message (which could have many attachments) has any attachments where the `ContentId` is `null` and if that `count` is greater than `0` then I want to return the `boolean` value in `HasAttachments`.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Edit your question and show the entire query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN 
        SUM(CASE WHEN a.ContentId IS NULL
                       AND a.message_id IS NOT NULL
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END) > 0 
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END as HasAttachments
```

From your narratives it seems like your inner Case Statement is missing another condition to determine when there is actually an attachment.  If you don't put in the second condition of when the AttachmentTable.message_id IS NOT NULL then you will count both messages that don't have any attachments and those messages that have attachments but no content id as the same thing.  But adding the a.message_id you limit that to just the case you seem to desire from your narrative.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way I might phrase the query:

```
select m.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from attachments a where a.message_id = m.message_id and content_id is null
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end) as HasAttachments
from messages m;
```

It is unclear why your query doesn't work, without the context of the rest of the query.